# Can Apple MDM see what youtube videos I have watched?

Tags: ipad, video, youtube, mdm

So I was just interested In how Apple MDM works and what my device manager could see. However i am not sure whether they can see what youtube videos I Have watched at home not on my school network.
I have provided a picture of all the rights on the mdm profile if you do need more info just tell me. By the way my youtube history was paused[image: picture of rights]

Answer (score 2):

[Page 10](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/resources/Managing_Devices_and_Corporate_Data_on_iOS.pdf)

MDM can see:

- Device name
- Phone number
- Serial number
- Model name and number
- Capacity and space available
- iOS version number
- Installed apps

MDM cannot see personal data such as:

- Personal or work mail, calendars, contacts, SMSes or iMessages
- Safari browser history
- FaceTime or phone call logs
- Personal reminders and notes Frequency of app use
- Device location